# PHP include in AJAX causes the Ajax response to be 'blind'

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax call that goes through to an actions page with lots of actions (actions.php) in it. In my ajax call it passes an ID which tells which action to use. On the "Send Sample Email" action, if you click it, the email gets sent and the action runs fine even returning a "Success" message in to the console. However, in the email action (on actions.php) the template is stored in an included file (sample-email.php).

In actions.php I have tried:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/emails/sample-email.php';
```

and

```
include('emails/sample-email.php');
```

Both 'work', even returning "Success" to the console log, however...

```
console.log(response);
if(response==="Success"){ 
    $.Notification.notify('success','top right','Email Sent', 'Email sent.')
location.reload(); 
} else {
    $.Notification.notify('error','top right','Error', 'There was a problem sending the email.')
}
```

Returns an error.

If I remove everything except for:

```
<?php
?>
```

Out of sample-email.php, it still shows an error... However if I remove that code too, it returns a success.

EDIT: Further digging found that the empty php file with just the php tags in is adding a blank space prior to "Success". I've added a space in my javascript if/else query and it's working. Odd though.

Comment: What is the error being shown? What is in the PHP error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the only error being shown is the notify error, so the if/else query for the value of response isn't happening correctly. In the console however, it is.

Comment: Go check the server's error logs for PHP errors.

Comment: No errors, I assume because as far as the PHP is concerned it's doing it's job. The fail point seems to be in the javascript if/else query and it not being able to see the value of response correctly. Although if I put console.log(response) in there, it reports the same value.